# How to disable automatic update of the correct GPU count for each MOM node in Torque?

Tags: cluster, gpu, torque

I have small installation of Toque 4.2.9. It is compiled with --enable-nvidia-gpus option. According to the documentation, when this option is used nodes file if automatically updated with the correct number of gpus. Is it possible to switch it off?

I ask about that because I want to temporary limit available resources. May be there is other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of solution for the problem is to recompile Torque without GPU support and creation of client packages. Then, newly created client packages (which does not support GPU) can be installed on the nodes on which you wish to disable GPUs.

One of the drawback of this approach is that you cannot select which GPUs are disabled. You can disable either all of them or none.
The second obvious drawback is that you have to do it on each node separately. It is not big issue if you have only several nodes or if you are using some kind of managing software. In my opinion, the problem is that it is wrong from conceptual point of view.